# Edit form with api data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in react that is filled with data from an api. I want to edit this data in the form, but i can not do it, because api always overwrite the fields.

This is my code:

```
let params = useParams();

const [student, setStudent] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    API.getStudentDetails(params.studentId).then(setStudent);
},[student]);




function editStudent(){
    API.editStudent(student).then(result => {
        if (result){
            alert("Estudiante modificado");
        }
    })
}

return(
    <>
        <div>Editar alumno {student.dni}</div>
        <div>
            <form id="formulario">
                ID<input type='text' id='id' disabled value={student.id} /> <br />
                DNI<input type='text' id='dni' value={student.dni} onChange={event => setStudent({...student, dni:event.target.value})} /><br />
                Nombre<input type='text' id='nombre' value={student.nombre} onChange={event => setStudent({...student, nombre:event.target.value})} /><br />
                Dirección<input type='text' id='direccion' value={student.direccion} onChange={event => setStudent({...student, direccion:event.target.value})}/><br />
                Edad<input type='number' id='edad' value={student.edad} onChange={event => setStudent({...student, edad:event.target.value})}/><br />
                Email<input type='text' id='email' value={student.email} onChange={event => setStudent({...student, email:event.target.value})}/><br />
                
                
                <button id='editar' onClick={() => editStudent()}>Editar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

How can do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `useEffect` hook. The `useEffect` will be called every time the `student` state is changed. You call `setStudent` on every form field changes which will trigger the `useEffect` which at the end will get the initial `student` data from the api.

What you can do is to remove the `student` from the `useEffect` array of dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {
    API.getStudentDetails(params.studentId).then(setStudent);
},[]);
```

With this, the `useEffect` will only be called when the component mount, or you can put `params.studentId` into the array if needed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    API.getStudentDetails(params.studentId).then(setStudent);
},[params.studentId]);
```